# Word 2010 - Keep border under last row at end of page in tables

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm often working in documents where there is a border on the outside of a table but none (or some) on rows.

At other times, I'm working with merged rows.

My question is - how do I set the borders so that it I will get a line under the last row at the end of a page EVERY TIME.

It's eluded me so far.  The attached is an example.  Ignore the gridlines.

[image]

Comment: I think you can only do that manually (or have the line for all rows).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply but that seems like madness.  I waste so much times putting in lines manually and then having to take them out when text is edited.  Surely there's an easier way?  Thanks again.

Comment: I suppose a VBA expert may wander by with a way to do it - but that's not me :/